# Ansible - change default datetime format?

Tags: ansible

I set `callbacks_enabled = profile_tasks` (in configuration) to track duration of tasks executed, though default datetime format seems to be quite strange. Seems to use some locality (though in Lithuania, we use ISO format):

```
TASK [docker-init : Install docker SDK] *****************************************************************
Pirmadienis 18 spalio 2021  22:46:19 +0300 (0:00:05.308)       0:00:19.873 **** 
ok: [v14-test]
```

Where could I change this datetime format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears [to be hard-coded](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix/blob/1.3.0/plugins/callback/profile_tasks.py#L100) as `strftime('%A %d %B %Y  %H:%M:%S %z')` so short of forking the collection and modifying that line, or [submitting an issue](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix/issues), I don't believe it's configurable

If you just need it fixed for this one case, you can edit the `profile_tasks.py` and patch it, since all things being equal ansible will not re-download the collection before running your playbook

Comment: Thanks, so strange that its hardcoded and with some weird long format. Reported issue: https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix/issues/279